# Removal of added portlet from Liferay portal page

Tags: liferay, portlet

I am using Liferay 6.1 (bundled with Tomcat 7.0.23) and Portlet with JSR 286.

I am able to add portlet onto the Liferay page, but am unable to remove it.

It is a simple portlet with a single button on it.

The problem is I am able to add multiple instances of the same portlet on a single page. Even after I shutdown and restart the server, the old added portlets are still there on the page.

Comment: are you able to remove other portlets (liferay portlets) from the page i.e. by clicking on the `x` icon on right-hand-top corner of every portlet?

Comment: I have the similar problems with liferay 5.x, we called this portlets the "Ghost-Portlets". And we have extended liferay core to solve it :)

Comment: @Mark: thanks for the reply but I am using Liferay 6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Let me know what you need, meaning do you need if your portlet has multiple instances on same page or not.

If you want that your portlet should have multiple instances then you have to make that portlet as `instanceable` portlet by specifying `<instanceable>true</instanceable>` in your `liferay-portlet.xml`, by default the value is `false`.

Also, You need to check following items to remove the portlet:

- Do you have rights (permissions) to remove the portlet. (like, admin, or
  similar custom role if created)
- Please check the `checkbox` at the top of the page (on the `dockbar`) named **Toggle Edit Control**.
- Portlet should not be included from theme.

Comment: @Prakash K : The 'X' icon is not appearing on the portlet. Do you know how to make it appear ?

Comment: Regarding the checks :    I have rights(permission) as I am the administrator. Toggle check boxes are not appearing , if you know how to make them appear kindly tell. I am not using any custom theme of my own.

Comment: Toggling the Edit Control worked . I was able to remove the portlets . Thanks !!

Comment: @Sameer, the X only appears in the Staging mode.

Answer (score 5):

I use a bit of hack for such portlets for which I dont see close  option. Hover over on any portlet for which you see the close icon on the same page and copy its link

```
http://localhost:8080/c/portal/update_layout?p_l_id=10141&p_p_id=56_INSTANCE_B9Xt&doAsUserId=&cmd=delete&referer=%2Fc%2Fportal%2Flayout%3Fp_l_id%3D10141%26doAsUserId%3D&refresh=1
```

Replace the value of p_p_id of the above url with the name of the portlet and then hit this url in the browser.

Comment: thanks for sharing the link , but none of the portlets are showing the close option/icon.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the left side vertical menu and click on "Modify Controls" where you see the covered eye. After this, you can see on all the portlets the settings Icon and you can remove each of them.